# Woocommerce: how to jump directly to product page when category only holds one item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a top menu which permits the display of product categories.
In this case, the name of the application I am selling.

When this menu item is clicked, it shows the contents of the category - as it should do.

However, as this category only contains one item, I want to jump straight to the product page, instead of displaying a category page with one item.

Here is a link to the page in question : [boutique.zimrahapp.com/categorie-produit/app/](http://boutique.zimrahapp.com/categorie-produit/app/)

I have not been able to find either a hook or a template where I can adjust the output or do a redirect.

Has this kind of thing already been done ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WooCommerce redirects a search query with only one result to that result. You can see how they are doing it [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L42-L49).

Modifying their code you get something like this:

```
function so_35012094_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    // Redirect to the product page if we have a single product
    if ( is_product_category() && 1 === $wp_query->found_posts ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $wp_query->post );
        if ( $product && $product->is_visible() ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $product->id ), 302 );
            exit;
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_35012094_template_redirect' );
```

Untested, so watch out for copy/paste fails. Always use [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) so you can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Cool, thanks @helgatheviking. Great answers as usual.

Answer (score 6):

The above code didn't work for me. I have a solution that works, but it redirects all single archive results. In my case I wanted to also redirect single tags.

```
/* Redirect if there is only one product in the category or tag, or anywhere... */

function redirect_to_single_post(){
global $wp_query;
if( is_archive() && $wp_query->post_count == 1 ){
the_post();
$post_url = get_permalink();
wp_safe_redirect($post_url , 302 );
 exit;
}
} 
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_single_post');
```

I had asked this same question here: [Woocommerce: How to automatically redirect to the single product if there is only one product on a category page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368001/woocommerce-how-to-automatically-redirect-to-the-single-product-if-there-is-onl/37370741#37370741)