# Woocommerce: How to automatically redirect to the single product if there is only one product on a category page?

Tags: redirect, woocommerce

I'm trying to skip the category archive page and go straight to the single product page when there is only one product in the category.

Here is the code I have so far, (not working):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_redirect_single_product_cat', 10 );

function woo_redirect_single_product_cat() {

global $wp_query, $wp;;

if  ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && 1 === $wp_query->found_posts  ) {

    $product = wc_get_product($wp_query->post->ID);

       if ( $product && $product->is_visible() ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $product->id ), 302 );
            exit;

       }
}
}
```

This code is modeled after the single search redirect in Woocommerce:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/fce8dc0868439474c24f7317af50ce7627f0d1c1/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L43

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, but not specifically for Woocommerce: (edit: now it is.)

```
/* Redirect if there is only one product in the category or tag, or anywhere... */

function redirect_to_single_post(){
global $wp_query;
if( (is_product_category() || is_product_tag()) && $wp_query->post_count == 1 )//Woo single only
//if( is_archive() && $wp_query->post_count == 1 )//redirect all single posts 
{
    the_post();
    $post_url = get_permalink();
    wp_safe_redirect($post_url , 302 );
exit;
}
} 
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_single_post');
```

In a way this is even better because it redirects for single tags as well.

Comment: Specifically to WooCommerece use this conditionals together  `is_product_category()` for product category and `is_product_tag()`for product tag: `if( (is_product_category() || is_product_tag()) && $wp_query->post_count == 1 ){…`

Comment: Thanks, that works! Editing the answer to include your conditional.

Comment: this code is working good for me on WooCommerce 4.4, thanks

Comment: Thanks, it still works for me on Woocommerce 5.5.2!

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your `functions.php` and this will work.!

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocom_redirect_if_single_product_in_category', 10 );
function woocom_redirect_if_single_product_in_category() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        $cat_name   =   sanitize_title( woocommerce_page_title( false ) );
        $args   =   array(
                "post_type"         => "product",
                "posts_per_page"    =>  -1,
                "product_cat"       => $cat_name
        );
        $posts  = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( count( $posts->posts ) == 1 ){
            $one_post_ID    =   $posts->posts;
            $ID =   $one_post_ID[0]->ID;
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $ID ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code redirected ALL category pages to a single product page.

Comment: @AJD Updated.! Please check now!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this fix, which worked! Only 1 hiccup. The rest of my pages show the left sidebar, but once I added this:

```
// WooCommerce Fix - Redirects to page if product is equal to one
add_action( 'template_redirect',
'woocom_redirect_if_single_product_in_category', 10 ); function
woocom_redirect_if_single_product_in_category() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        $cat_name   =   sanitize_title( woocommerce_page_title( false ) );
        $args   =   array(
                "post_type"         => "product",
                "posts_per_page"    =>  -1,
                "product_cat"       => $cat_name
        );
        $posts  = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( count( $posts->posts ) == 1 ){
            $one_post_ID    =   $posts->posts;
            $ID =   $one_post_ID[0]->ID;
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $ID ) );
        }
    } }
```

it made my template show a broken sidebar pushed into the footer, while the other single product pages show up correctly. There is probably a call in the script that is misconfiguring the sidebar position, its probably calling the default single product page template. If anyone has a fix for this it would be much appreciated because it is a bit beyond my abilities.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the accepted answer version. I don't know if the one you are using ever worked properly.

Comment: Yep, I tried it and it worked, issue was a unclosed php tag wrapping the whole function file and an extra div in the product itself.   \_( ' _ ' ) _/  +1'd the first answer.