# Woocommerce - Can a subcategory with a single product jump to the single product page?

Tags: woocommerce, categories, elementor

I'm using elementor, woocommerce and Ocean WP theme.

I've managed to get most of my store functioning how I want, however, there is a category I have for schools. Under the schools category are subcategories which are each school I want to sell something to - School A, School B, etc. Each of these will only have a **single product**.

At the moment if you click on the subcategory it goes to the archive of products...of which theres one...and then you have to click that to go to the actual product page. **Is there a way to bypass this archive page and go straight to the individual product?**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce: how to jump directly to product page when category only holds one item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012094/woocommerce-how-to-jump-directly-to-product-page-when-category-only-holds-one-i)